# Converting seconds to HH:mm:ss?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, time, momentjs

I am getting hours exceed two charecter, when I am trying to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss format.

```
var seconds = 4287050531;
var getTime = formatTime(seconds);
console.log("Time Is :"+getTime);// 1190847:22:11 

function formatTime(seconds) {
  return [pad(Math.floor(seconds/3600)),
          pad(Math.floor(seconds/60)%60),
          pad(seconds%60),
          ].join(":");
}

function pad(num) {
  if(num < 10) {
    return "0" + num;
  } else {
    return "" + num;
  }
}
```

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? Truncate any hours above 24?

Comment: i used 24 also but showing wrong result,function formatTime(seconds) {
      return [pad(Math.floor(seconds/3600)%24),
              pad(Math.floor(seconds/60)%60),
              pad(seconds%60),
              ].join(":");
    }

Comment: what is the expected result

Comment: @shreyaS tell us what's your expected result should be. Because normally this format is used to show time for a single day so maximum seconds of a day can be `60*60*24` which is `86400` but your second variable exceeds that. So that's why you are getting hours exceeding two characters.

Comment: Expected result is HH:mm:ss but hour is coming greater than two charecter (1190847:22:11 )

Comment: The input seems in milliseconds and you are treating it as second.

Comment: hour part should be like `pad(Math.floor(seconds/3600%24))`

Comment: here in your example hours can definitely go > 99 as input is in  seconds and input/3600 can be any number based on your input.

Comment: if i use pad(Math.floor(seco‌​nds/3600%24)) then, for 318311 seconds its showing 16:25:11, and for 4287050531 second its showing 15:22:11 as output

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with below function:

```
 function convert(seconds) {
    seconds = Number(seconds);
    var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds % 3600 / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 3600 % 60);
    return ((hours > 0 ? hours + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") : "") + minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") +`enter code here` seconds); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use  moment-duration-format module

```
npm install moment-duration-format

var moment = require("moment-duration-format");

moment.duration(seconds, "seconds").format("h:m:s");
```

https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: moment.duration(...).format is not a function

Comment: require the module moment.

Answer (score 0):

Why take all the trouble?

Try this:

```js
(function () {
  
    function checkTime(i) {
        return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    function startTime() {
        var today = new Date(),
            h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
            m = checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
            s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());
            return h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        
       
    }
   setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById('yourTime').innerHTML =  startTime();
        }, 1000);
  
})();
```

```html
<div id="yourTime">
```

Comment: That will not work if the seconds add up to more than 24 hours.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

Using this can can easily convert it

```
(new Date).clearTime()
          .addSeconds(4287050531)
          .toString('H:mm:ss');
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).clearTime is not a function

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
first add date.js file then try this